# How can I initiate `genericBean` with some managed bean as a default value at the beginning of an application?

Tags: java, jsf

If I had a generic bean in a JSF page. Like this:

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{genericBean.content}"/>
```

and this bean was not a managed bean, i.e. in faces-config there were only 2 managed beans :

```
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>bean1</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>mb.Bean1</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>bean2</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>mb.Bean2</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

and if both of these beans had a method getContent() :

```
public class Bean1{
  public String getContent(){
       return "Content of Bean 1";
  }
}
```

and

```
public class Bean2{
  public String getContent(){
       return "Content of Bean 2";
  }
}
```

then I could change genericBean with the one of them :

```
Bean1 bean1 = new Bean1();
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("genericBean", bean1);
```

or

```
Bean2 bean2 = new Bean2();
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("genericBean", bean2);
```

according some business logic.

As you see I am using `genericBean` just as a label in faces context. Now my question is: How can I initiate `genericBean` with a `bean1` as a default value at the beginning of an application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an application scoped (managed) bean and set the default value for your generic bean in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ServletContextListener` to achieve this

```
public class CustomApplicationContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private static final String FOO = "foo";

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        Bean1 bean1 = new Bean1();
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("genericBean", bean1 );
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {

                event.getServletContext().removeAttribute("genericBean");

    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.yourpackage.CustomApplicationContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You should use an application scoped bean in jsf 2.0 style and mark it as `eager`

```
@ManagedBean(name="genericBean", eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class GenericBean {
 ...
}
```